# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rule Issue

Tags: magento

I have a client that is looking to implement the following.

- No Discount for any sales between $0 & $249.99
- 5% Discount for Sales between $250 & $499.99
- 10% Discount for Sales between $500 & $999.99
- 15% Discount for Sales over $1000

I have no problem implementing the the above. This is where the fun begins.

The client has some items that are not on sale and not part of the discount, therefore this throws me out abit as I had originally had the discount working on the basis of the subtotal of the cart. This is ok for items that are all for sale.

This is an example for 2 items.

one at 500 and another at 600 = 1100. Then the cart would discount 15% from the total.

Now lets say the $600 isn't a sale item. then I would need the rule to to discount 15% from the $500 item only. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest here would probably create a Yes/No attribute (call it 'has_sale'). Make sure the attribute has 'Use for Promo Rule Conditions' set to 'Yes'. Then set the value of it to 'No' on all of the products that are not in sale.

Appropriately set conditions based on the totals of sale items:

[image]

Make sure the discounts only apply to sale items:

[image]